# How to reset jupyter notebook theme to default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using the jupyter notebook installed with Anaconda (I'm on Mac). Few days ago, I wanted to change the theme to have a dark background, and I followed the [instructions here](http://sherifsoliman.com/2016/01/11/theming-ipython-jupyter-notebook/). Namely, I've downloaded the theme `custom.css` and placed it in `~/.jupyter/custom/`. It worked very well.

I liked the theme, but I would like to go back to the default one (this one does not show the main toolbar, among other things). I tried to remove the `custom.css` from its folder, I reset my terminal, but nothing changes! I'm guessing that jupyter keeps a copy of the themes somewhere that I should delete, but I can't find it.

I have also tried uninstalling jupyter and reinstalling, following the commands:

```
conda update conda
conda uninstall ipython
conda install jupyter
```

Again, no change. I'm stuck with my black background theme with no toolbar.

Comment: Don't forget to refresh the browser page

Comment: The currently selected Jupyter theme maybe found in this file: `~/.jupyter/custom/current_theme.txt`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My previous suggestion of deleting the `custom/` directory doesn't do the trick. `jupyter` caches the `custom.css` file in other directories that are tricky to clear all together. If it doesn't find a folder `custom` with `.css` file inside it it looks in other locations to pick up a `.css` file. 
Also, I'm not sure if every location is actually deleted when you uninstall `jupyter`.

The easiest solution is to delete the old `custom.css` and replace it with a new empty `custom.css` file. `jupyter` picks that up and goes back to its default look.

Answer (score 93):

An easier way might be to do:

```
pip install jupyterthemes
```

Now you can choose from the following given themes and activate it like this

```
# list available themes
# onedork | grade3 | oceans16 | chesterish | monokai | solarizedl | solarizedd
jt -t <THEME_NAME>
```

In order to reset your theme to the default theme just use

```
jt -r
```

For all information and more, visit [github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes)

Comment: I get `command not found: jt` when i use `jt -r`. How do I reset to default theme?

Comment: @TheTank you should install jupyterthemes before

Comment: @TheTank also if you had a virtual environment activated when you pip-installed it, make sure you are in the same virtual environment when you UN-install it!

Comment: I couldn't `pip install jupyterthemes`, instead `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterthemes` works :)

Answer (score 19):

I am hoping that you used `pip install jupyterthemes` to get the custom themes.

The following are the steps that take you from **installation** of new themes to the resetting of the same to **default**.

```
pip install jupyterthemes 

jt -l (List of all themes)

jt -t <THEME NAME> (to implement a theme)

jt -r (to reset the notebook to default)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

In order to reset your theme type in cmd

`jt -r`

delete the directories returned by console. Now restart the notebook server.

Answer (score 10):

Close any instances of jupyter notebook.
Open Anaconda prompt.
Run "pip install jupyterthemes"
This should show you the themes installed/ cached by jupyter notebook.

[image: Running pip install jupyterthemes]

Now run "jt -r" to reset the theme to default as shown below.

[image]

Open and test jupyter notebook. Theme should be gone now. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 6):

On windows running jt from the notebook, one has to precede the jt command with the !.

```
!jt -t oceans16 (my choice)

!jt -r
```

Answer (score 4):

in Anaconda prompt simply run 
`jupyter`
then,
`jt -r`

Answer (score 3):

in command prompt type jupyter then press enter and then type jt -r it will surely work

Answer (score 2):

If you are having trouble viewing the tool bar you can put this code in:

```
!jt -t solarizedd -T -N -kl
```

Where:
Toolbar Visible `-T`
Name & Logo Visible `-N`
Kernel Logo Visible `-kl`
their defaults are set to none

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie and had problems with all of the above solutions and all I wanted was to set it back to default. I was stuck in a dark mode theme. Instead, I found that going to C:\Users\"Username_Here"\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages and finding the "jupyter themes" folders and deleting them entirely. Set everything back to default. There were 2 folders to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually trying to change the font size of the dark theme and wrote the command -
`jt -fs 200`
and it actually changed the theme back to the default one.

Comment: It works probably but it isn't a proper way to solve the problem because the reason is a bug - the `-fs` flag should only change font size as you tried to.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reinstall `jupyter-notebook`, the problem is with `jupyterthemes`.

You can reset current theme to default with: `jt -r`,
or just set the same theme with prefered flags which enable:

- toolbar: `-T`
- filename and logo: `-N`
- kernel logo: `-kl`

e.g. `!jt -t monokai -T -N -kl`

---

If you don't like the new shape `jupyterthemes` imposes on `jupyter-notebook`, I can recommend `jupyter-themer` which is easier to use and is not effecting the default shape of `jupyter-notebook` at all.

Installation: `pip install jupyter-themer`

Repositorium with documentation and examples (*for now, examples are stored in a not merged pull-request): [@github: jupyter-thamer](https://github.com/transcranial/jupyter-themer)

My favourite customization: `jupyter-themer -b dark -c zenburn`.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this

```
! jt -r
```

then refresh to Jupiter notebook

Answer (score -3):

Just go to the c drive and users directory. there you can see jupyter directory . delete it completely and freshly again start jupyter notebook by clicking ananconda shell. that is all needed.
simple issue .